# Test Coverage - Exclude The Android SDK

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, testing, code-coverage

When I run test with coverage, it includes the entire Android SDK.

[image]

How do I exclude it so that I get an accurate number?

Answer (score 3):

You can add your app package in default JUnit configuration like-

[image]

And it should include only your package.

Comment: Is there a way to do it on gradle level?